# Change name of CSRF filter in Tomcat 9

Tags: java, csrf, csrf-protection, tomcat9

By default tomcat CSRF filter is generating ID like

org.apache.catalina.filters.CSRF_NONCE=C6D6CB73AC793EC7BC55BADA791A5DE3

i want to change the name from org.apache.catalina.filters.CSRF_NONCE to MY_NONCE